# How to short a data filling function?

Tags: c#, optimization, coding-style, dataset, conventions

I have some C# examples here, which i actually want to know how i can optimize them. I want to cut down the codeexample to the minimum. Is there a practical way to refactor the `GetDetails` in the `Tour` class or should i refactor it in the `CombiTour` class? And of course, how can i refactor it.

```
public class Tour
{
    public string zielID;
    public string ort;
    public string strasse;
    public string nummer;
    public string plz;
    public string land;
    public string name;
    public string fahrtNummer;

    public Tour(string zielID)
    {
        this.zielID = zielID;
    }
}

public class CombiTour
{
    public List<Tour> touren;

    public CombiTour()
    {
        this.touren = new List<Tour>();
    }

    public void GetDetails()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < touren.Count; i++)
        {
            DataSet dsDetails = Tools.oGenericDs("SELECT Strasse, Nummer, PLZ, Ort, Land, Fahrtnummer FROM Ziele WHERE ZielID = " + this.touren[i].ZielID);
            this.touren[i].Strasse = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Strasse"].ToString();
            this.touren[i].Nummer = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Nummer"].ToString();
            this.touren[i].PLZ = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PLZ"].ToString();
            this.touren[i].Ort = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ort"].ToString();
            this.touren[i].Land = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Land"].ToString();
            this.touren[i].Fahrtnummer = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fahrtnummer"].ToString();

            dsDetails = Tools.oGenericDs("SELECT Name FROM Kunden WHERE ZielID = " + this.touren[i].ZielID);
            this.touren[i].Name = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty ok without using other tools (see the answer). You should not concatenate your query as this is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: How else can i put the statement together?

Comment: Use parameters for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an ORM (a light one like [ORMLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite), or a heavyweight one like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx)) and have that do the legwork for you converting data to and from POCOs.

Literally, my code for getting data out of a database using OrmLite is:

```
var myProducts = connection.Query<Product>("SELECT * FROM Product");
```

And I get back a collection of products.  You don't even need the hand-written SQL (though in more complex cases, you might).

EF also makes heavy use of LinqToSQL, which means you're rarely (if at all) bothering with hand-written SQL and are always dealing with first-class POCOs and LINQ to do all the conversions.

Comment: I want to solve the issue without thirdparty applications, possibly trough linq? Im not very experienced in C# though.

Comment: They're frameworks rather than 3rd-party applications and ORMs are getting more and more prevalent rather than writing all the code as shown.

Comment: I also want to understand how these frameworks do this. For me its more important to learn how something gets better than how to know a way to do something.